# How to force oracle to execute subquery for every row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I want to select random value from the second table for each record in the first one. The problem is that it seems like this value is always the same for every row meaning that it is executed only once for all rows. How could I achieve that?

```
create table first_table(name varchar2(100));
insert into first_tablevalues('John');
insert into first_tablevalues('Jessie');
insert into first_tablevalues('Jack');

select * from second_table;
create table second_table(id number);
insert into second_table(id) values(1);
insert into second_table(id) values(2);
insert into second_table(id) values(3);
insert into second_table(id) values(4);
insert into second_table(id) values(5);
insert into second_table(id) values(6);
```

Then I executed this query, but for every name in the first table I get the same number.

```
SELECT NAME,
       (SELECT id
          FROM (SELECT id
                  FROM second_table
                 ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
         WHERE rownum = 1)
  FROM first_table;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A correlation clause fixes the problem:

```
SELECT NAME,
       (SELECT id
        FROM (SELECT id
              FROM second_table st
              ORDER BY dbms_random.value
             )
        WHERE rownum = 1 AND ft.name IS NOT NULL
       )
FROM first_table ft;
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/TPLC8612) is a rextester.

Comment: I'm sorry but not only did it not work but also duplicated my result set three times (once for each name I guess).

Comment: Now it's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is *ugly* but - kind of *works*.

```
SQL> WITH ri
  2       AS (SELECT s.id,
  3                  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) rn,
  4                  COUNT (*) OVER (ORDER BY NULL) cnt
  5             FROM second_table s),
  6       rn
  7       AS (SELECT f.name,
  8                  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, ri.cnt))
  9                     rn
 10             FROM first_table f JOIN ri ON 1 = 1)
 11    SELECT rn.name, MAX (ri.id) id
 12      FROM rn JOIN ri ON rn.rn = ri.rn
 13  GROUP BY rn.name;

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
Jack                3
John                2
Jessie              6

SQL> /

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
John                5
Jack                6
Jessie              4

SQL> /

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
Jack                6
John                2
Jessie              4

SQL> /

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
Jack                5
John                6
Jessie              3

SQL> /

NAME               ID
---------- ----------
John                6
Jack                3
Jessie              1

SQL>
```

Comment: The most important thing is that it works! Thank you I appreciate this.

Comment: You're welcome. Though, Gordon's query seems to be way better.